# odient: "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python

I have been using odient in python for a project and it's been working completely fine. I did the same thing I always do for this problem and for some reason it keeps saying my defined function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given, even though it's been fine doing problems like this before. Here is my code:

```
    def sy(J):
        Ntot=J[0]
        xb=J[1]
        dNtotdt=nn2-nv
        dxbdt=(-nv*xb-xb*dNtotdt)/Ntot
        return[dNtotdt,dxbdt]
    #odeint requires that we set up a vector of times (question asks for 0-10)
    t_val=np.linspace(0,10,46) #46 for more accuracy
    #we also need to make an initial condition vector
    Yo=np.array([Ntoto,xbo])
    #use odient function to find the concentrations
    ans=odeint(sy,Yo,t_val)
    print(ans)
```

please help

Comment: Please post a complete stack trace.

Comment: And please post enough code that we can reproduce your question, including any necessary imports for a straight cut and paste. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're expecting this line `Yo=np.array([Ntoto,xbo])` to pass the entire list to `J`, but it's passing it as separate arguments. The smallest change you can make to fix this problem, is to add an asterisk before `J`. `sy(*J)`. Essentially, you create an alias for `*args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your derivative function passed to [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) needs to expect 2 inputs (y and t), the most straight forward solution is to just make your function take multiple arguments as you seem to have forgotten.

```py
def sy(J,t):
```

Answer (score -1):

In the error it clearly mentioned that the function "Odient" takes 1 positional argument but you are trying to put more than 1 argument example.

```py
#This function take one Parameter "var"
def foo(var):
 return var

#Calling the function with print statement

print(foo(var, var2)) #Trying to give more than 1 argument. But it gives error
```

Like this you are doing with your code.

Comment: did you even read the docs ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: Why i could read the docs ?? I gave the answer by seeing the error.

Comment: putting some thought and effort into the answers will benefit you more than the person you are answering, and it's a very good way to learn new skills.